# web.py global variables in module base

Tags: python, singleton, web.py

Three module exists. Cfg, Main and Component

### Cfg.py

```
value = 0
```

### Component.py

```
import Cfg

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return Cfg.value
```

### Main.py

```
from Test import Cfg
import Component

urls = ('/', 'Component.index')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Cfg.value = 1
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Get method of Component.Index returns 0, but i'm expecting 1. What did i miss?

### Edit #1

first modification main.py to test :

```
from test import Cfg
import Component
import test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    importedCfg = id(Cfg)
    cfgInComponent = id(Component.Cfg)
    cfgInTest = id(test.Cfg)

    print importedCfg, cfgInComponent, cfgInTest
    print importedCfg == cfgInComponent == cfgInTest
```

Result :

> 36202928 36203088 36202928
>   False

Second modification in main.py :

```
import Cfg
import Component

if __name__ == '__main__':
    importedCfg = id(Cfg)
    cfgInComponent = id(Component.Cfg)
    # cfgInTest = id(test.Cfg)

    print importedCfg, cfgInComponent
    print importedCfg == cfgInComponent
```

> 36858160 36858160 True

if you do not want to create multiple instance you should follow the second way.

Comment: edited the question. the problem was all modules are in module named 'Test'. and main.py calling the Cfg with 'from Test import Cfg' but component.py calls cfg by 'import Cfg'. two calling style should be same to work as expected.

Comment: is `return Cfg.Value` intentional or was the uppercase `V` an accident? I can't reproduce your example here.

Comment: no 'v' is lowercase. fixed question again. i'm working with pycharm as ide.  My first comment solved the problem for pycharm. But i can't reproduce problem when working in console. calling 'python main.py' and it says 'ImportError: cannot import name Cfg' and it works in ide somehow(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the result of:

```
from Test import Cfg
import Component

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert id(Cfg) == id(Component.Cfg)
```

and

```
import Cfg
import Component

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert id(Cfg) == id(Component.Cfg)
```

this means that doing a "from module" import creates different instances of `Cfg`. (I wasn't aware of this either).

This behavior is present in Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 (Python 2.6 wasn't tested).

Answer (score 1):

What can happen is that if your pythonpath contains both the parent directory of your package, and a subdirectory of your package, you can end up with a situation where python believes that it has imported different modules, because it got to them different ways.

Here is a complete, working, example.

```
import tempfile
import sys
import os

base = tempfile.mkdtemp()
os.mkdir(os.path.join(base, 'examplepackage'))

f = open(os.path.join(base, 'examplepackage', '__init__.py'), 'w')
f.close()
f = open(os.path.join(base, 'examplepackage', 'bar.py'), 'w')
f.write('a = 1')
f.close()

sys.path.append(base)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(base, 'examplepackage'))

import examplepackage.bar as package_bar
import bar
bar.a = 2
print bar.a
print package_bar.a
print [m for m in sys.modules.keys() if 'bar' in m]
```

You will see that `bar.a` has changed, and `package_bar.a` has not. You will also see that there are two modules in the `sys.modules` cache, both with 'bar' in the name. That dictionary is where modules are put after import, keyed on their name.